# Search results showing incorrect domain name

Tags: dns, seo, shopify

I just recently started my shopify store, as with all shopify sites my site has a X.myshopify.com url. However, I have a domain, X.com, that points at the same ip as the myshopify.com. The problem is that in search results (Google), the myshopify.com link is showing up instead of my main domain. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you cant get shopify to redirect the shopify domain to the proper domain then ensure the shopify domain has canonical tags pointing to the proper domain and the proper domain should replace indexing in time.